# Unable to load class named [io.jsonwebtoken.io.JacksonSerializer] from the thread context, current, or system/application

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jwt, jjwt

I got this error message while login in to the spring-boot application from postman. I used JWT webtoken for authentication and authorization. Please help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Check with your **pom.xml**

*Dependecies to be added -*
jjwt-api version 0.11.2 ,
jjwt-impl vesrion 0.11.2 ,
jjwt-jackson vesrion 0.11.2

from *https://mvnrepository.com*
Adding latest version of them worked fine for me.